# Dependency javax.mail:mail:1.4 not found

Tags: maven, dependencies, jakarta-mail, pom.xml

After I imported a maven project in IntelliJ IDEA, there are two errors in the pom.xml file:

> "Failed to read artifact descriptor for javax.mail:mail:jar:1.4"
>
> "Dependency javax.mail:mail:1.4 not found"

Does anyone know the reason behind these errors and how can I fix them?

Thank you and have a great day!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Due to license restrictions the older java mail classes are not in maven central or the java.net repository. usually companies host their own maven proxy and add these classes there.

Since around version 1.4.5 the dependencies are available in the [java.net](https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/mail/javax.mail/) repository. Some later versions are also in [maven central](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:com.sun.mail%20AND%20a:javax.mail&core=gav).

All other versions need to be downloaded from the [oracle website](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index-138643.html) and either added to a maven proxy or to your local maven repository - for example using the dependency plugin.

Comment: JavaMail 1.4 is ancient.  Use JavaMail 1.6.3, the details are [here](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 5):

Change the pom.xml to include:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Or if you have a build.gradle file in the dependencies section add:

```
    compile "com.sun.mail:jakarta.mail:1.6.3"
```