# JavaMail repository for maven not found

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I want to import this dependency:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api/1.6.2

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

in my maven project from Intellij, but I get an error at `artifactId` and `version`:

```
Dependency 'javax.mail:javax.mail-api:1.6.2' not found
```

Comment: Due to license restrictions the older java mail classes are not in maven central or the java.net repository. usually companies host their own maven proxy and add these classes there.

Since around version 1.4.5 the dependencies are available in the java.net repository. Some later versions are also in maven central.

All other versions need to be downloaded from the oracle website and either added to a maven proxy or to your local maven repository - for example using the dependency plugin.

See : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53687816/dependency-javax-mailmail1-4-not-found]

Comment: You can use the non Oracle alternative [`jakarta.mail`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/jakarta.mail/1.6.4). Don't get confused, it is just a different name (and as well as Java is, Jakarta is an Indonesian island).

Comment: Strange, I can get it on a Maven project. Do you have Maven installed on your system?

Comment: @KubNetwork version 1.6.2 is in mvnrepository.com, why don't download it?

Comment: @EugenCovaci no

Comment: Try to reimport Maven projects from the Maven tab.

Comment: Are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: @EugenCovaci no

Comment: Can you build project from command line by Maven?

Comment: @Andrey yes. `mvn clean install` -> `BUILD SUCCESS`, but in Intellij still appear with red at dependency.

Comment: @Andrey hmm ... I restarted IDE and now it works(maybe because of `mvn clean install` ... interesting. Thank you!